# As good as That/they/them ? are

Tags: adverbs

> Opportunities as good as **that** are ____
>
> a. scarce, b. peculiar, c. weird, d. unconventional

I don't understand why "**that**" is used in this sentence.

If I were to create such a sentence I would write "Opportunities as good as **they** are scarce"

What is the difference? Do they have same meaning?

- Opportunities as good as **that** are scarce
- Opportunities as good as **them** are scarce
- Opportunities as good as **they** are scarce

Do all of them have same meaning?

Comment: _That_ implies _that one_ (referring to a single very good opportunity). If you were referring to several good opportunities, you could use _as good as those_.

Comment: *You're funny. People **as funny as you** are rare* is perfectly natural English. But for the third person plural context, it's normally *They're funny. People **as funny as them** are rare*. Exceptionally, you could use the "subject pronoun" form *People **as funny as they are** are rare* - but this really needs that relatively clumsy repetition of ***are***, so it's not great. Note that *People as funny as you **are are** rare* is also "valid", but because "you" can be both "subject" ***and*** "object" pronoun, we don't ***have*** to repeat the verb (and hence ***wouldn't usually do so***).

Answer (score 1):

> [1] Opportunities as good as that are scarce.

> [2] Opportunities as good as them are scarce.

> [3] [o]pportunities as good as they are scarce [no full stop]

As what Kate says, *that* refers to a single good opportunity, and we could say *as good as those* when we refer to several good opportunities.

[1] is a complete sentence and describes the scarcity of such good opportunities.

[2] is unusual.

To compare the subject with several good opportunities, we could say

> [2a] Opportunities as good as *those* are scarce.

Similarly, [2a] is a complete sentence and describes the scarcity.

[3] equates *how good* the opportunities are to their *scarcity*.  It is a noun phrase and not a complete sentence.